# Can I change the size and margin of <g> or firefox has a bug?

Tags: html, css, svg

I have the next code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>example00</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        aaaaaaaaaaaa
        <div data-id="95" id="map">
                        <style type="text/css">
                svg {
                    margin: 0;
                }
                g {
                    margin: 0;
                }
            </style>
            <svg height="500px" width="100%" pointer-events="all" style="border: 2px solid red;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <g class="viewport" transform="translate(-1134.8008037565835,-465.99275413153373)scale(2.7132086548953445)">
                    <g transform="translate(722.22 125)"><circle id="node_1" class="node" style="fill: rgb(50, 50, 128);" r="6"/></g>
                    <g transform="translate(572.22 158.33)"><circle id="node_2" class="node" style="fill: rgb(50, 50, 128);" r="6"/></g>
                    <g transform="translate(805.56 208.33)"><circle id="node_10" class="node" style="fill: rgb(50, 50, 128);" r="6"/></g>
                    <g transform="translate(722.22 241.67)"><circle id="node_11" class="node" style="fill: rgb(50, 50, 128);" r="6"/></g>
                    <g transform="translate(838.89 225)"><circle id="node_12" class="node" style="fill: rgb(50, 50, 128);" r="6"/></g>
                    </g>
                </svg>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I think that the svg groups has not margins and align.

And the group elements in for example Chromium (fork Chrome) is shown good in the inspector, as you see in the screenshot:

[image: chromium]

But the firefox is shown with margins and a align a few to the right, as you see in the screenshot:

[image: firefox]

is it a bug? or is it something that I miss it in the code?

Comment: Is it really that the object location changes or is it that the tools get the position wrong. I suspect the latter.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug. I found a small example to test:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>example00</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <b>The border is the trap!!!!</b>
        <br />
        <svg height="200" width="200" style="border: 30px solid red;">
            <g class="first">
              <circle cx="20" cy="20" r="20" fill="green"></circle>
              <circle cx="70" cy="70" r="20" fill="purple"></circle>
            </g>
            <g class="second">
              <rect x="110" y="110" height="30" width="30" fill="blue"></rect>
              <rect x="160" y="160" height="30" width="30" fill="red"></rect>
            </g>
        </svg>
        <br />
        <b>This is without border and some love.</b>
        <br />
        <svg width="200" height="200">
            <g class="first">
              <circle cx="20" cy="20" r="20" fill="green"></circle>
              <circle cx="70" cy="70" r="20" fill="purple"></circle>
            </g>
            <g class="second">
              <rect x="110" y="110" height="30" width="30" fill="blue"></rect>
              <rect x="160" y="160" height="30" width="30" fill="red"></rect>
            </g>
        </svg>
    </body>
</html>
```

The problem is the border changes the positions of `<g>`.

These are the screenshots with the bug in firefox:

[image: firefox_border_is_a_trap.jpg]

[image: firefox_without_border.jpg]

And this is the screenshot in chromium (and it runs fine):

[image: chromium_runs_fine.jpg]

Comment: Yes it is reported some minutes ago: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1250143

Comment: So the problem is not that the drawing is wrong, it is that the tools are reporting the wrong location for the shapes?

Comment: No, the inspector tools runs fine, because my example is a small part of a project with svg and the library jquery library tooltipster. And this library puts incorrectly the tooltip for this bug.

Comment: I find the question and the bugzilla bug confusing then. `<svg>` elements should support the border property, `<g>` elements should not. That seems to be the case in the screenshots.