# Change HTML <g> size

Tags: html, css, svg

I want to change the size of `Rocket` in below source code: 
https://jsfiddle.net/umaar/4FMyA/ 
I have been trying many ways, but still has no effect. 
Actually, I want to make the Rocket a bit smaller.

Thanks

```css
/*=============================================
[ Page Setup ]
==============================================*/

body {
  background: #34495e
}

#pageWrap {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#rocket {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 150px;
}


/*=============================================
[ Inactive State Styles ]
==============================================*/

.rocket_inner {
  transform: translateY(15px) translateX(-3px);
  -webkit-transition: .3s;
  -moz-transition: .3s;
  transition: .3s;
}

.icon_circle {
  transition: .2s;
  fill: #22303e;
}

.large_window_path {
  transition: .2s;
  fill: #22303e;
}

.small_window_path {
  fill: #22303e;
}

.wing_shadow {
  fill: #34495e;
}

.rocket_bottom {
  fill: #34495e
}

.rocket_base {
  fill: #34495e
}

.rocket_shadow {
  fill: #34495e
}

.window_grandient {
  stop-color: #2DCB73
}

.window_grandient1 {
  stop-color: #2AC16D
}

.window_grandient2 {
  stop-color: #29B968
}

.window_grandient3 {
  stop-color: #28B767
}

.wing_base {
  fill: #34495e
}

.fire_path {
  fill: #FC0
}


/*=============================================
[ Hover Styles ]
==============================================*/

.rocket_wrap:hover .rocket_base {
  fill: #FFFFFF !important;
  stroke-width: 0px !important;
}

.rocket_wrap:hover .rocket_shadow {
  fill: #EDEDED !important;
  stroke-width: 0px !important;
}

.rocket_wrap:hover .icon_circle {
  fill: #282e3a !important;
  stroke: #fff !important;
  stroke-width: 7px !important;
}

.rocket_wrap:hover .small_window_path {
  fill: #28B767 !important;
  stroke-width: 0px !important;
}

.rocket_wrap:hover .wing_shadow {
  display: block !important;
  fill: #FC9252 !important;
}

.rocket_wrap:hover .wing_base {
  fill: #E16E36 !important;
  stroke-width: 0px !important;
}

.rocket_wrap:hover .rocket_bottom {
  fill: #2DCB73 !important;
  stroke-width: 0px !important;
}

.rocket_wrap:hover .large_window_path {
  fill: url(#SVGID_2_) !important;
  stroke-width: 0px !important;
}

.rocket_wrap:hover .rocket_inner {
  transform: translateY(0px) translateX(-3px) !important;
}


/*=============================================
[ Animation Classes ]
==============================================*/

.fire {
  display: none;
  animation-delay: 0s;
  fill-opacity: 1;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  stroke-width: 0px;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  animation-direction: normal;
}

.rocket_wrap:hover #fireLeft {
  display: block;
  animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-name: fireLeft, fillOpacity1;
  animation-duration: 1.2s;
}

.rocket_wrap:hover #fireMiddle {
  display: block;
  animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-name: fireMiddle, fillOpacity1;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}

.rocket_wrap:hover #fireRight {
  display: block;
  animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-name: fireRight, fillOpacity1;
  animation-duration: 1.3s;
}

.rocket_wrap:hover #fireSmallLeft {
  display: block;
  animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-name: fireSmall, fillOpacity2;
  animation-duration: 1.3s;
  transform-origin: bottom;
}

.rocket_wrap:hover #fireSmallRight {
  display: block;
  animation-delay: 0.3s;
  animation-name: fireSmall, fillOpacity3;
  animation-duration: 1.6s;
  transform-origin: bottom;
}


/*=============================================
[ KeyFrame Animations ]
==============================================*/

@keyframes fireSmall {
  10% {
    transform: rotate(17deg) translateY(1px)
  }
  20% {
    transform: rotate(-13deg) translateY(2px)
  }
  30% {
    transform: rotate(21deg) translateY(3px)
  }
  40% {
    transform: rotate(-34deg)translateY(4px)
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(24deg) translateY(5px)
  }
  60% {
    transform: rotate(-17deg) translateY(6px)
  }
  70% {
    transform: rotate(31deg) translateY(7px)
  }
  80% {
    transform: rotate(-28deg) translateY(8px)
  }
  90% {
    transform: rotate(14deg) translateY(9px)
  }
  99% {
    transform: rotate(0deg) translateY(10px)
  }
}

@keyframes fireLeft {
  6% {
    transform: rotate(25deg)
  }
  15% {
    transform: rotate(-19deg)
  }
  25% {
    transform: rotate(25deg)
  }
  32% {
    transform: rotate(-30deg)
  }
  46% {
    transform: rotate(22deg)
  }
  54% {
    transform: rotate(-29deg)
  }
  61% {
    transform: rotate(32deg)
  }
  74% {
    transform: rotate(-9deg)
  }
  83% {
    transform: rotate(16deg)
  }
  99% {
    transform: rotate(0deg)
  }
}

@keyframes fireMiddle {
  10% {
    transform: rotate(25deg)
  }
  20% {
    transform: rotate(-25deg)
  }
  30% {
    transform: rotate(30deg)
  }
  40% {
    transform: rotate(-22deg)
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(29deg)
  }
  60% {
    transform: rotate(-45deg)
  }
  70% {
    transform: rotate(37deg)
  }
  80% {
    transform: rotate(-15deg)
  }
  90% {
    transform: rotate(16deg)
  }
  99% {
    transform: rotate(0deg)
  }
}

@keyframes fireRight {
  15% {
    transform: rotate(17deg)
  }
  23% {
    transform: rotate(-13deg)
  }
  37% {
    transform: rotate(21deg)
  }
  45% {
    transform: rotate(-34deg)
  }
  54% {
    transform: rotate(24deg)
  }
  67% {
    transform: rotate(-17deg)
  }
  72% {
    transform: rotate(31deg)
  }
  84% {
    transform: rotate(-28deg)
  }
  96% {
    transform: rotate(14deg)
  }
  99% {
    transform: rotate(0deg)
  }
}

@keyframes fillOpacity1 {
  0% {
    fill-opacity: 1;
    stroke-opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    fill-opacity: 1;
    stroke-opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    fill-opacity: 0;
    stroke-opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes fillOpacity2 {
  0% {
    fill-opacity: 1;
    stroke-opacity: 1;
  }
  25% {
    fill-opacity: 1;
    stroke-opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    fill-opacity: 0;
    stroke-opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes fillOpacity3 {
  0% {
    fill-opacity: 1;
    stroke-opacity: 1;
  }
  67% {
    fill-opacity: 1;
    stroke-opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    fill-opacity: 0;
    stroke-opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes rocektMove {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0px)
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(20px)
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- http://www.pencilscoop.com/2013/11/animate-svg-icons-with-css3-jquery/ -->

<div id="pageWrap">
  <svg version="1.1" x="0px" y="0px" width="307px" height="283px" id="rocket">

<g class="rocket_wrap">

<circle cx="147.5" cy="138.6" r="105.5" class="icon_circle"/>

<g class="rocket_inner">

<path class="fire fire_path"  id="fireMiddle" d="M148.891,179.906c3.928,0,7.111,3.176,7.111,7.094 c0,7.78-7.111,16-7.111,16s-7.111-8.349-7.111-16C141.78,183.082,144.963,179.906,148.891,179.906z"/>



<path class="fire_path fire" id="fireRight" d="M154.063,181.092c3.577-1.624,7.788-0.048,9.408,3.52 c3.216,7.084,0.139,17.508,0.139,17.508s-9.927-4.662-13.09-11.63C148.9,186.923,150.487,182.715,154.063,181.092z"/>


<path class="fire_path fire" id="fireLeft" d="M143.392,182.519c3.25,2.207,4.098,6.623,1.896,9.864 c-4.372,6.436-14.873,9.238-14.873,9.238s-1.191-10.902,3.108-17.23C135.725,181.149,140.143,180.312,143.392,182.519z"/>



<path class="fire_path fire" id="fireSmallLeft" d="M143.193 187.531c2.226 0.4 3.7 2.6 3.2 4.8 c-0.875 4.407-5.829 8.264-5.829 8.264s-3.09-5.53-2.229-9.865C138.807 188.5 141 187.1 143.2 187.531z"/>



<path class="fire_path fire" id="fireSmallRight" d="M152.089 188.599c2.043-0.985 4.496-0.132 5.5 1.9 c1.952 4 0.3 10.1 0.3 10.107s-5.795-2.56-7.713-6.541C149.186 192 150 189.6 152.1 188.599z"/>


<path class="rocket_bottom" d="M157.069 171.31h-3.292c-1.562-0.048-3.178-0.076-4.846-0.076 s-3.284 0.028-4.846 0.076h-3.292c-7.277-7.938-12.371-26.182-12.371-47.434c0-28.54 9.182-51.676 20.508-51.676 c11.327 0 20.5 23.1 20.5 51.676C169.44 145.1 164.3 163.4 157.1 171.31z"/>

<g id="right_wing_wrap">
<path class="wing_base" d="M166.678 127.161c0 0 17.7 3.3 12.9 48.099l-18.06-14.05 L166.678 127.161z"/>
<path class="wing_shadow" d="M158.225 140.336c10.481-5.584 22.7 22.2 21.4 34.9 l-18.06-14.05C161.542 161.2 156.1 144.3 158.2 140.336z"/>
</g>

<g id="left_wing_wrap">
<path class="wing_base" d="M135.131 161.21l-18.06 14.1 c-4.805-44.793 12.924-48.099 12.924-48.099L135.131 161.21z"/>
<path class="wing_shadow" d="M135.131 161.21l-18.06 14.1 c-1.367-12.746 10.896-40.509 21.377-34.924C140.614 144.3 135.1 161.2 135.1 161.21z"/>
</g>

<g id="rocket_body_wrap">
<path class="rocket_base" d="M162.728 167.358c-3.778-0.623-8.573-0.996-13.796-0.996 s-10.018 0.373-13.795 0.996c-5.033-10.186-8.257-25.808-8.257-43.338c0-30.688 9.873-55.566 22.052-55.566 s22.053 24.9 22.1 55.566C170.984 141.6 167.8 157.2 162.7 167.358z" />
<path class="rocket_shadow" d="M145.464 166.417c19.578-40.575 7.26-85.229 4.112-98.067 c11.88 0.9 21.4 25.4 21.4 55.525c0 17.529-3.225 33.152-8.257 43.337c0 0-3.786-0.472-8.069-0.697 S145.464 166.4 145.5 166.417z"/>
</g>

<g id="large_window_wrap">
<radialgradient id="SVGID_2_" cx="148.9" cy="112.5" r="15.2" fx="139.4853" fy="112.5239" gradientunits="userSpaceOnUse">
<stop offset="0" class="window_grandient"/>
<stop offset="0.5868" class="window_grandient"/>
<stop offset="0.6834" class="window_grandient"/>
<stop offset="0.6845" class="window_grandient1"/>
<stop offset="0.6861" class="window_grandient2"/>
<stop offset="0.6897" class="window_grandient3"/>
</radialgradient>
<circle class="large_window_path" cx="148.9" cy="111.3" r="10.5"/>
</g>

<circle class="small_window_path" cx="148.9" cy="132.4" r="5.2"/>

</g>

</g>
</svg>
</div>
```

for any suggestion.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/35555625/215552

Comment: you should post your code here for posterity sake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may simply use scale on the most upper `g` and adjust position by adding a translation if needed:

```css
/*=============================================
[ Page Setup ]
==============================================*/

body {
  background: #34495e
}

#pageWrap {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#rocket {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 150px;
}


/*=============================================
[ Inactive State Styles ]
==============================================*/

.rocket_inner {
  transform: translateY(15px) translateX(-3px);
  -webkit-transition: .3s;
  -moz-transition: .3s;
  transition: .3s;
}

.icon_circle {
  transition: .2s;
  fill: #22303e;
}

.large_window_path {
  transition: .2s;
  fill: #22303e;
}

.small_window_path {
  fill: #22303e;
}

.wing_shadow {
  fill: #34495e;
}

.rocket_bottom {
  fill: #34495e
}

.rocket_base {
  fill: #34495e
}

.rocket_shadow {
  fill: #34495e
}

.window_grandient {
  stop-color: #2DCB73
}

.window_grandient1 {
  stop-color: #2AC16D
}

.window_grandient2 {
  stop-color: #29B968
}

.window_grandient3 {
  stop-color: #28B767
}

.wing_base {
  fill: #34495e
}

.fire_path {
  fill: #FC0
}


/*=============================================
[ Hover Styles ]
==============================================*/

.rocket_wrap:hover .rocket_base {
  fill: #FFFFFF !important;
  stroke-width: 0px !important;
}

.rocket_wrap:hover .rocket_shadow {
  fill: #EDEDED !important;
  stroke-width: 0px !important;
}

.rocket_wrap:hover .icon_circle {
  fill: #282e3a !important;
  stroke: #fff !important;
  stroke-width: 7px !important;
}

.rocket_wrap:hover .small_window_path {
  fill: #28B767 !important;
  stroke-width: 0px !important;
}

.rocket_wrap:hover .wing_shadow {
  display: block !important;
  fill: #FC9252 !important;
}

.rocket_wrap:hover .wing_base {
  fill: #E16E36 !important;
  stroke-width: 0px !important;
}

.rocket_wrap:hover .rocket_bottom {
  fill: #2DCB73 !important;
  stroke-width: 0px !important;
}

.rocket_wrap:hover .large_window_path {
  fill: url(#SVGID_2_) !important;
  stroke-width: 0px !important;
}

.rocket_wrap:hover .rocket_inner {
  transform: translateY(0px) translateX(-3px) !important;
}


/*=============================================
[ Animation Classes ]
==============================================*/

.fire {
  display: none;
  animation-delay: 0s;
  fill-opacity: 1;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  stroke-width: 0px;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  animation-direction: normal;
}

.rocket_wrap:hover #fireLeft {
  display: block;
  animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-name: fireLeft, fillOpacity1;
  animation-duration: 1.2s;
}

.rocket_wrap:hover #fireMiddle {
  display: block;
  animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-name: fireMiddle, fillOpacity1;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}

.rocket_wrap:hover #fireRight {
  display: block;
  animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-name: fireRight, fillOpacity1;
  animation-duration: 1.3s;
}

.rocket_wrap:hover #fireSmallLeft {
  display: block;
  animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-name: fireSmall, fillOpacity2;
  animation-duration: 1.3s;
  transform-origin: bottom;
}

.rocket_wrap:hover #fireSmallRight {
  display: block;
  animation-delay: 0.3s;
  animation-name: fireSmall, fillOpacity3;
  animation-duration: 1.6s;
  transform-origin: bottom;
}


/*=============================================
[ KeyFrame Animations ]
==============================================*/

@keyframes fireSmall {
  10% {
    transform: rotate(17deg) translateY(1px)
  }
  20% {
    transform: rotate(-13deg) translateY(2px)
  }
  30% {
    transform: rotate(21deg) translateY(3px)
  }
  40% {
    transform: rotate(-34deg)translateY(4px)
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(24deg) translateY(5px)
  }
  60% {
    transform: rotate(-17deg) translateY(6px)
  }
  70% {
    transform: rotate(31deg) translateY(7px)
  }
  80% {
    transform: rotate(-28deg) translateY(8px)
  }
  90% {
    transform: rotate(14deg) translateY(9px)
  }
  99% {
    transform: rotate(0deg) translateY(10px)
  }
}

@keyframes fireLeft {
  6% {
    transform: rotate(25deg)
  }
  15% {
    transform: rotate(-19deg)
  }
  25% {
    transform: rotate(25deg)
  }
  32% {
    transform: rotate(-30deg)
  }
  46% {
    transform: rotate(22deg)
  }
  54% {
    transform: rotate(-29deg)
  }
  61% {
    transform: rotate(32deg)
  }
  74% {
    transform: rotate(-9deg)
  }
  83% {
    transform: rotate(16deg)
  }
  99% {
    transform: rotate(0deg)
  }
}

@keyframes fireMiddle {
  10% {
    transform: rotate(25deg)
  }
  20% {
    transform: rotate(-25deg)
  }
  30% {
    transform: rotate(30deg)
  }
  40% {
    transform: rotate(-22deg)
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(29deg)
  }
  60% {
    transform: rotate(-45deg)
  }
  70% {
    transform: rotate(37deg)
  }
  80% {
    transform: rotate(-15deg)
  }
  90% {
    transform: rotate(16deg)
  }
  99% {
    transform: rotate(0deg)
  }
}

@keyframes fireRight {
  15% {
    transform: rotate(17deg)
  }
  23% {
    transform: rotate(-13deg)
  }
  37% {
    transform: rotate(21deg)
  }
  45% {
    transform: rotate(-34deg)
  }
  54% {
    transform: rotate(24deg)
  }
  67% {
    transform: rotate(-17deg)
  }
  72% {
    transform: rotate(31deg)
  }
  84% {
    transform: rotate(-28deg)
  }
  96% {
    transform: rotate(14deg)
  }
  99% {
    transform: rotate(0deg)
  }
}

@keyframes fillOpacity1 {
  0% {
    fill-opacity: 1;
    stroke-opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    fill-opacity: 1;
    stroke-opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    fill-opacity: 0;
    stroke-opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes fillOpacity2 {
  0% {
    fill-opacity: 1;
    stroke-opacity: 1;
  }
  25% {
    fill-opacity: 1;
    stroke-opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    fill-opacity: 0;
    stroke-opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes fillOpacity3 {
  0% {
    fill-opacity: 1;
    stroke-opacity: 1;
  }
  67% {
    fill-opacity: 1;
    stroke-opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    fill-opacity: 0;
    stroke-opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes rocektMove {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0px)
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(20px)
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- http://www.pencilscoop.com/2013/11/animate-svg-icons-with-css3-jquery/ -->

<div id="pageWrap">
  <svg version="1.1" x="0px" y="0px" width="307px" height="283px" id="rocket">

<g class="rocket_wrap" transform="scale(0.5)">

<circle cx="147.5" cy="138.6" r="105.5" class="icon_circle"/>

<g class="rocket_inner">

<path class="fire fire_path"  id="fireMiddle" d="M148.891,179.906c3.928,0,7.111,3.176,7.111,7.094 c0,7.78-7.111,16-7.111,16s-7.111-8.349-7.111-16C141.78,183.082,144.963,179.906,148.891,179.906z"/>



<path class="fire_path fire" id="fireRight" d="M154.063,181.092c3.577-1.624,7.788-0.048,9.408,3.52 c3.216,7.084,0.139,17.508,0.139,17.508s-9.927-4.662-13.09-11.63C148.9,186.923,150.487,182.715,154.063,181.092z"/>


<path class="fire_path fire" id="fireLeft" d="M143.392,182.519c3.25,2.207,4.098,6.623,1.896,9.864 c-4.372,6.436-14.873,9.238-14.873,9.238s-1.191-10.902,3.108-17.23C135.725,181.149,140.143,180.312,143.392,182.519z"/>



<path class="fire_path fire" id="fireSmallLeft" d="M143.193 187.531c2.226 0.4 3.7 2.6 3.2 4.8 c-0.875 4.407-5.829 8.264-5.829 8.264s-3.09-5.53-2.229-9.865C138.807 188.5 141 187.1 143.2 187.531z"/>



<path class="fire_path fire" id="fireSmallRight" d="M152.089 188.599c2.043-0.985 4.496-0.132 5.5 1.9 c1.952 4 0.3 10.1 0.3 10.107s-5.795-2.56-7.713-6.541C149.186 192 150 189.6 152.1 188.599z"/>


<path class="rocket_bottom" d="M157.069 171.31h-3.292c-1.562-0.048-3.178-0.076-4.846-0.076 s-3.284 0.028-4.846 0.076h-3.292c-7.277-7.938-12.371-26.182-12.371-47.434c0-28.54 9.182-51.676 20.508-51.676 c11.327 0 20.5 23.1 20.5 51.676C169.44 145.1 164.3 163.4 157.1 171.31z"/>

<g id="right_wing_wrap">
<path class="wing_base" d="M166.678 127.161c0 0 17.7 3.3 12.9 48.099l-18.06-14.05 L166.678 127.161z"/>
<path class="wing_shadow" d="M158.225 140.336c10.481-5.584 22.7 22.2 21.4 34.9 l-18.06-14.05C161.542 161.2 156.1 144.3 158.2 140.336z"/>
</g>

<g id="left_wing_wrap">
<path class="wing_base" d="M135.131 161.21l-18.06 14.1 c-4.805-44.793 12.924-48.099 12.924-48.099L135.131 161.21z"/>
<path class="wing_shadow" d="M135.131 161.21l-18.06 14.1 c-1.367-12.746 10.896-40.509 21.377-34.924C140.614 144.3 135.1 161.2 135.1 161.21z"/>
</g>

<g id="rocket_body_wrap">
<path class="rocket_base" d="M162.728 167.358c-3.778-0.623-8.573-0.996-13.796-0.996 s-10.018 0.373-13.795 0.996c-5.033-10.186-8.257-25.808-8.257-43.338c0-30.688 9.873-55.566 22.052-55.566 s22.053 24.9 22.1 55.566C170.984 141.6 167.8 157.2 162.7 167.358z" />
<path class="rocket_shadow" d="M145.464 166.417c19.578-40.575 7.26-85.229 4.112-98.067 c11.88 0.9 21.4 25.4 21.4 55.525c0 17.529-3.225 33.152-8.257 43.337c0 0-3.786-0.472-8.069-0.697 S145.464 166.4 145.5 166.417z"/>
</g>

<g id="large_window_wrap">
<radialgradient id="SVGID_2_" cx="148.9" cy="112.5" r="15.2" fx="139.4853" fy="112.5239" gradientunits="userSpaceOnUse">
<stop offset="0" class="window_grandient"/>
<stop offset="0.5868" class="window_grandient"/>
<stop offset="0.6834" class="window_grandient"/>
<stop offset="0.6845" class="window_grandient1"/>
<stop offset="0.6861" class="window_grandient2"/>
<stop offset="0.6897" class="window_grandient3"/>
</radialgradient>
<circle class="large_window_path" cx="148.9" cy="111.3" r="10.5"/>
</g>

<circle class="small_window_path" cx="148.9" cy="132.4" r="5.2"/>

</g>

</g>
</svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You cannot add style to an SVG `<g>` element. Its only purpose is to group children. That means, too, that style attributes you give to it are given down to its children, so a fill="green" on the `<g>` means an automatic `fill="green"` on its child `<rect>` (as long as it has no own fill specification).

Your only option is to add a new `<rect>` to the SVG and place it accordingly to match the `<g>` children's dimensions.

Comment: i don't agree with this ... yes g is used to group but we can apply style on it like adding a translation or a mask, etc